# Java:confused about CMS garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I know the CMS garbage collector uses the mark sweep algorithm,I am curious about how it marks the object.

CMS initial mark: why does it mark the reachable objects rather than mark unreachable objects?

Comment: JVM does not mark *unreachable* objects because... it obviously cannot *reach* them :) I mean, by walking through the graph of references. In order to find unreachable objects, JVM needs to iterate over the whole heap and exclude live objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The garbage collector's task is to find objects that your program can no longer reach by following whatever chain of accessor steps, and to reclaim the memory occupied by them.

The Mark-Sweep GC does that the other way round: it first finds all objects that can still be reached, and then reclaim the memory of all the other objects.

Simplified Mark-Sweep algorithm (of course the real one is far more complex):

- Start with all directly-reachable references, e.g. local variables on the stack (arguments and locals from all not-yet-finished method calls), static fields etc.
- Mark the objects they point to.
- Recursively inspect the newly-marked objects. Mark the objects referenced by their fields.
- Repeat until you get no more new marks.
- Loop over your memory object-by-object and reclaim the memory of every object without a mark.
- Finally remove all marks.

Comment: Tanks，are there any ways to find the unreachable objects?

Comment: Loop over memory to find all objects that are not referenced,such as reference counting.Why not use this way？

Comment: Reference counting is inferior. It will not reclaim cycles, e.g. A referencing B, and B referencing A, and nothing else referencing A or B. Both have a reference count of 1, so they stay in memory although they are garbage.

Comment: You ask "are there any ways to find the unreachable objects"? The garbage collector can, as he knows where the memory blocks lie that he has to sweep for unmarked objects. The application program cannot, because all objects that the application program can reach, aren't garbage by definition.